# How can I call an event of a class with the click of a button in main?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I have a certain class in tkinter that has an event, bound to buttons within that class, that packs or unpacks a frame within the class (it's a flyout menu). The event is *expandmenu* I would like to call this event from main, outside this class. I have created an instance of this class called "inst1", but when I bind it to a button such that;

```
button1.bind('<Button-1>', inst1.expandmenu)
```

, nothing occurs when I click the button. The actual class inst1 still works fine and the event is called from within the class it works and the menu opens. I can't open the menu by calling this event from outside. How can I achieve this? there should be a way to call the event in the INSTANCE.EVENT format, right? 
Thanks!

Comment: Your terminology is a bit confusing. `expandmenu` isn't a valid event. Do you mean that `expandmenu` is a method bound to an event? That's what the code implies. Please try to post a [mcve] that replicates the problem in as few lines as possible.

Comment: expandmenu is an event defined in the custom class I created. as in:
Class myClass: 
       def__init__(self):
               *adding objects
       def expandmenu(self, event):
              * does the thing I want

inst1 is an instance of myclass.

Comment: That's not an event. That's a method.

Comment: Bryan Oakley - methods and events as I understand them are a bit different, or perhaps an event is a special kind of method?  for all intents and purposes, it's a method, but I've defined it with (self, event) which allows me to call it from a bind statement easily. it looks like this limits it scope too, though... What am I misunderstanding about how events work differently from normal methods?

Comment: Methods and events are very different things. An event is not a method, or anything like a method. An event is a notification that something happened. Methods can be called in response to an event. Events work differently from normal methods because events aren't methods. Maybe you're confusing an event _handler_ with an _event_. An _event handler_ is a method. An _event_ is simply a notification that something happened. An event is a keypress, or a window being resized, or a mouse being moved.